# Keep NuGet packages private

Tags: c#, deployment, nuget

My solution uses NuGet packages from a private feed. I would like to keep these NuGet packages private. However, when I copy the .exe file to be used for deployment I am forced to copy the NuGet package's corresponding .dll file in order for the .exe file to run. There is nothing stopping someone from copying and using that .dll in another application.

Is there any known solution to this problem? I can't even figure out how to embed the NuGet.

Comment: Why do you want to keep your NuGet packages private?

Comment: You can't reference something, if you don't deploy it. Try going to work without your phone, then try texting from your phone is what you just described. Nuget = sharing to me. Don't give you app away anywhere you don't trust the people. Or go through the nightmare of the Microsoft Store, but I wouldn't send my worst enemy there after my experience. I am in the store and can't access my own account.

Comment: I want to keep my NuGet packages private because even though they are under copy-write, other people could use them illegally. I was hoping there was a method to embed the NuGet package similar to embedding a Dll. A NuGet package seems simpler to update than a copied, embedded Dll.

Comment: If you're using .NET Core you can publish to a single executable and even trim the references so all the libraries that you use will be linked directly into the EXE and no one will see the dlls anymore.

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework so that won't work sadly. I know there are third party applications that can do something similar though. I was hoping that as NuGet packages were supposed to be better than copy-pasting the Dll, NuGet packages could similarly be embedded.